# Is there a way in Access reports to show only one of each item but all of its attributes?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm not sure exactly how to explain it but basically I want to go from something like this

[image]

to this

[image]

Comment: You can handle this in different ways - either through sql or through the report object(s). I would vouche for making the SQL do the job, but Lee (from below)  thinks it might be easier to do so with the report itself. Im not sure that it really matters which one you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method would be to create a report from your query, add a group to the report grouping by the `Food` field, and place the `Food` field within the group header.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I needed! Thanks!